# Nesting dynamic links into a dynamic list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to create a function that creates a dynamic menu. Ive been able to create the "a" tags and give them individual links while also assigning them ID's. The problem is that I cant get the links inside of a list where my CSS applies its rules.

```
function write_navBar() {
var links = ["intro.html", "art.html", "portfolio.html", "guides.html", "about_me.html"]
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.getElementById("mainNav").appendChild(ul);
for (i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++) {
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var text = document.createTextNode(links[i]);

    a.href = links[i];
    a.id = "mainNav";
    a.text = links[i];

    document.getElementById("mainNav").appendChild(a);
                                    }
}
```

Any suggestions on cleaning the code while keeping to javascript would be appreciated. And also any explanation of syntax would be also appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `a.id = "mainNav";`. Looks buggy. You already have an element with that id.

Comment: You have `var ul = document.createElement("ul");` twice. Remove the 2nd one.

Comment: This line isn't doing anything useful: `var text = document.createTextNode(links[i]);`. Remove it too.

Comment: Then the UL list would then need the id for the CSS rules to be applied to my menu.

Comment: Use the `class` attribute for the CSS rules that must apply to multiple elements. The `id` attribute must be unique across the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function write_navBar() {
  var links = ["intro.html", "art.html", "portfolio.html", "guides.html", "about_me.html"];
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  var li, a, text;
  for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; ++i) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    a  = document.createElement('a');
    text = document.createTextNode(links[i]);

    a.href = links[i];
    a.setAttribute("class", "some-class-name");
    a.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);

  }
  document.querySelector("#mainNav").appendChild(ul);
}
```

• Use querySelector over getElementById. Both work, but theres a performance boost to querySelector. The API is close to jQuery and most (if not all) newer browsers support querySelector.

• Append the ul AFTER you've added the elements again for performance reasons.

• Use an LI to hold the link element, a second UL wont do what you want.

• Don't resuse id's, the thing you would want to use is a class, they basically do the same thing but javascript treats id's and classes differently. If that doesnt fit your needs, try a compound CSS selector in your css such as:
`#mainNav ul li a { /* styles here */ }`

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the .querySelector, its a huge tool that i've been missing out on. And i completely forgot to correctly appendChilds to other elements properly. A relief!

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that you append the correct items to the correct parents. Scanning your code I assume you want the following HTML output:

```
<div id="mainNav"> // this is already there
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="intro.html">intro.html</a>
        </li>
        ... // repeat for other items in the array
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can modify your code like this to get the above result:

```
function write_navBar() {
    var links = ["intro.html", "art.html", "portfolio.html", "guides.html", "about_me.html"]
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    document.getElementById("mainNav").appendChild(ul);
    for (i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var a = document.createElement("a");

        a.href = links[i];
        a.className = "some-class-to-target-in-your-css";
        a.innerText = links[i];

        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: The links are placed outside of the LI. Although, the LI are now nested in the UL, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't that bad. I at one time took a similar outlook towards doing these. However, I am now of the belief it is far more testable, reliable, and easier to build these as actual templates, clone them, and populate them through a factory pattern.

In your setup, you have a parent `ul`, and then build multiple `ul`'s with `a`'s in them -- I am going to assume you meant to nest `li` elements -- and so that is what this will do.

Here is how I would approach that in your scenario.

Step 1: Build a the template, and create the styling and visual effect.

```css
.navLink a{
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuTemplate">
  <li class="navLink"><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Simple style, I know. But it is just for simplicity, you can really do whatever you want there to style the example. Note that it is a simple structure, so all you are really seeing in there is a template, an `li` element, and the `a` element.

What we are also going to add to the style definition in our use case is

```
.menuTemplate{
  display:none;
}
```

Because we don't actually want to see the template, we just want to use it. Next, we will create a factory for these.

```
var navFactory = new function(){
    var template = document.querySelector('.menuTemplate .navLink');

    this.Create = function(text,href){
        var nav = template.cloneNode(true);
        var link = nav.querySelector('a');
        link.href = href;
        link.innerText = text;
        return nav;
    }
};
```

The last step is to simply take your element that will hold the nav elements - you named this "mainNav" above - and fill it in from the factory.

```js
var navFactory = new function(){
  var template = document.querySelector('.menuTemplate .navLink');

  this.Create = function(text,href){
    var nav = template.cloneNode(true);
    var link = nav.querySelector('a');
    link.href = href;
    link.innerText = text;
    return nav;
  }
};

function write_navBar() {
 var links = ["intro.html", "art.html", "portfolio.html", "guides.html", "about_me.html"];
 var navUl = document.querySelector('#mainNav ul');
 for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  navUl.appendChild(navFactory.Create(links[i],links[i])); 
 }
}

write_navBar();
```

```css
.menuTemplate{
  display:none;
}

.navLink a{
  padding:3px;
  opacity:0.85
}

.navLink a:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuTemplate">
  <li class="navLink"><a></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="mainNav">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking all the time to put together this code snippet, Although I was shown a simpler way to create the menu, I will be using your method in a different dirrection, I hadnt thought about creating the elements ahead of time and then filling them in with functions. What i dont understand is the reason for the template.

Comment: @MitchellAckerman - It may be a little harder to tell from this simple example, but complex structure can become very lengthy to do purely in code. It is also a lot harder to view the progress of the template or html structure when it is code only, especially when there are many elements involved. I use this approach sometimes with very large template pieces, and it would simply be too much time to have composed the elements in script versus html.